# rails use helper in partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, helper, partial

I have a shared partial in

```
-shared
└──-foo
   └──-bar
      └──baz.html.erb
```

And in it I'm trying to access a helper method in

```
-helpers
└──foo_helper.rb
```

But I am getting un `undefined method` error.

How can I include that helper method in my partial in an elegant way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put

```
helper :foo
```

in your application controller.  This should make the helpers in foo_helper available across all actions.